# r - random sampling- small change in probabilities, similar order of results

Tags: r, random, simulation, seed

Using sample.int in R I am drawing random samples for two populations (in the example, 10 individuals). If there is a small change in the probabilities, like a change from c(0.5,0.5) to c(0.51, 0.49) I would like the the sampling to be more or less maintained, i.e. most individuals would be assigned the same draw (e.g. if we had a population of 100, maybe 1 individual would change their assignment). How might this be done?

```
set.seed(123)
probs.1<-c(0.51,0.49)
sample.int(n=2,
           replace = TRUE,
           size=10,
           prob=probs.1)
#[1] 1 1 2 2 2 2 1 1 2 1

set.seed(123)
probs.2<-c(0.5,0.5)
sample.int(n=2,
           replace = TRUE,
           size=10,
           prob=probs.2)
#[1] 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 2
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this? If you want identical draws you should use the same seed and same probabilities. Otherwise you're just making two separate random draws from different distributions (even if they are similar), so setting the seed doesn't actually do anything. Having said that, I suspect you may see the sort of thing you want if you change probs to something like (0.1,0.9) and (0.11,0.89).

Comment: So the idea is that we have a microsimulation with 100 people getting treatment A, and then we rerun the simulation with these 100 people getting treatment B instead. Treatment B has a small impact on the probabilities, so we would expect that for most people their outcome would be unchanged, but a few would have a different outcome under the alternative

Comment: In which case you want a product distribution. So sample1 * sample2 like `rbinom(100, 1, 0.5) * rbinom(100, 1, 0.01)` then you can control the seeds better. So `set.seed(1); s1 <- rbinom(100,1,0.5); set.seed(2); s2 <- rbinom(100,1,0.1); s1 * s2`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this is base your second sample on your first, but just make each subject have a small probability of changing group:

```r
set.seed(123)
probs.1 <- c(0.5, 0.5)
sample1 <- sample.int(2,  100, TRUE, probs.1)
sample2 <- ifelse(sample1 == 1, 1 + rbinom(length(sample1), 1, 0.02), 2)
```

This means the samples are almost the same:

```r
head(sample1)
#> [1] 2 1 2 1 1 2

head(sample2)
#> [1] 2 1 2 1 1 2
```

But a single subject (in this example) has switched group:

```
table(sample1)
#> sample1
#>  1  2 
#> 47 53

table(sample2)
#> sample2
#>  1  2 
#> 46 54
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>